# Why Does The Highlighted Region Go Away?

Tags: region, mark, selection

I want to be able to select multiple lines and move them up and down as a block, while "jumping" over the line in the direction of moving. Here's the code for moving up:

```lisp
(defun on-ctrl-shift-up ()
    (move-selected-lines-up))

(defun move-selected-lines-up ()
    (let (
        (left-position (min (mark) (point)))
        (right-position (max (mark) (point))))

        (if (not (= (line-number-at-pos left-position) (line-number-at-pos (point-min))))
            (let ()
                (transpose-regions
                    (line-beginning-position (+ 1 (- (line-number-at-pos left-position) (line-number-at-pos (point)))))
                    (line-end-position (+ 1 (- (line-number-at-pos right-position) (line-number-at-pos (point)))))
                    (line-beginning-position (- (line-number-at-pos left-position) (line-number-at-pos (point))))
                    (line-end-position (- (line-number-at-pos left-position) (line-number-at-pos (point)))))))))
                    
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-<up>") (lambda () (interactive) (on-ctrl-shift-up)))
```

So when I select two lines and I want to move them up, this is what I would want to get:

- Item1
- `Item2`
- `Item3`
- Item4

Upon pressing `C-S-<up>`:

- `Item2`
- `Item3`
- Item1
- Item4

But instead, I get this:

- Item2
- Item3
- Item1
- Item4

Meaning, the highlighted text gets cleared, so I can't repetitively press the shortcut, I have to select the two lines again and then press the shortcut. When I check after the command execution `region-active-p` and `use-region-p`, they are both true.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select non-contiguous regions in Emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12218/how-to-select-non-contiguous-regions-in-emacs)

Comment: Short answer to "why?": Emacs region is generally contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `transient-mark-mode` turned on.

Comment: I don't think so, because it behaves in the same way, whether the `transient-mark-mode` is on or not.

Comment: Without `transient-mark-mode`, the region is not highlighted at all. It is on by default, so I suspect that @db48x is correct. See the doc string with `C-h f transient-mark-mode` to learn when the highlighting goes away (e.g. it does so when the buffer changes, as you have experienced). The highlighting comes back when the `mark` is reactivated.